# Database Relationship - Syntax

Tags: python, database, syntax, sqlalchemy

A question on the syntax involved in SQLAlchemy.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Why is it ForeignKey('child.id') and not ForeignKey("Child.id")?
Why is it relationship("Child") and not relationship("child")?  Is there something fundamental about how databases and SQLAlchemy work that I don't understand which is why I have to ask this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`relationship(Child)` is also valid. By capitalising inside string, sqlalchemy  will look for respective model.

Relationship isn't sql standard so SQLAlchemy is using its own convention, whereas ForeignKey is SQL Standard so `tablename.column` is used.

Answer (score 2):

**In general**: A `relationship` is defined on `orm` level while `ForeignKey` represents a database model. Now, it well might be the case that `sqlalchemy` is smart enough to figure from from the other, but if you keep this separation in mind, you are safe.

**Specifically to your question**: just read the documentation. Extract below (verbatim)

- From [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship):

> **argument** – a mapped class, or actual Mapper instance, representing the
>   target of the relationship.
>
> argument may also be passed as a callable function which is evaluated
>   at mapper initialization time, and may be passed as a **Python-evaluable
>   string** when using Declarative.

- From [`ForeignKey`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey)

> **column** – A single target column for the key relationship. A Column
>   object or **a column name as a string**: `tablename.columnkey` or
>   `schema.tablename.columnkey`. `columnkey` is the key which has been
>   assigned to the column (defaults to the column name itself), unless
>   link_to_name is True in which case the rendered name of the column is
>   used.